# Opening facebook app through another app

Tags: ios, facebook, parsing

Hi I am trying to open the Facebook app when users click a button within my app. What I have done is link the users to their Facebook profile so that I can capture their user ID. Then I am querying their ID and trying to pass it through to a button on their "profile". Unfortunately this isn't working on my simulator. I'm not sure if it is because the simulator doesn't have the Facebook app, or because there is a flaw within the syntax. Could someone please shed some light on this for me. I was wondering how you could open Facebook profile in the Facebook app with the click of a button. In my sign up page I have user's link their Facebook account, and in the button I retrieve the Facebook id and link it to the Facebook app URL. It doesn't run in the simulator, but this could be that it isn't hooked up to the Facebook app maybe? Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
- (IBAction)fbProfile:(id)sender {

FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
        NSString *facebookID = userData[@"id"];
        NSMutableString *fbProfile = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"fb://profile/"];
        [fbProfile appendString:facebookID];
        NSURL *profileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:fbProfile];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: profileURL];
    }
}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work on the simulator because it does not have the Facebook app installed and hence does not have the Facebook URL handler registered. Try it on a device.